# I made a typo in a new tag name, how can I correct that?

Tags: support, tags, retag-request

I would like to introduce [.net-attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-attributes), but I incorrectly typed [.net-attibutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-attibutes) (without the `r`).

How do I resolve that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's done:

I just edited those two questions you added the tag to, removing the bad tag and adding the one you wanted.

This night (3 UTC), the bad tag will be pruned unless it gains new questions.

BTW: The new tag might still benefit from a tag-wiki and excerpt.

As a follow-up, if the wrong tag is similar enough, it can block creation of the proper tag. Either get a mod to do the rename then, or untag, let the orphaned tag be pruned, and *then* retag properly.

Comment: Thanks. I added the tag wiki and excerpt, and added a 'DO NOT USE' to the wrong tag.

Comment: Don't see your suggestion for the proper tag, only the one for the typo tag.

Comment: Hmm, i just redid it. Maybe it was left behind in the review?

Comment: Well, now both have two approves.

Comment: @Deduplicator .. pls look here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317082/i-made-a-tag-but-unfortunately-screwed-up-the-name  thanks