# How can I correct a tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just created a tag called [ruby2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby2.3), but for consistency with other versions, I should have made it [ruby-2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-2.3). I would like to rename the tag rather than creating a synonym. How can I do that?

**Edit** It looks like it does not even allow me to create [ruby-2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-2.3) because there already is [ruby2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby2.3) and probably they are too close.

Comment: Moderators can do a rename, IIRC. We can't do that ourselves.

Comment: *just created* ... Then why don't rollback that and create a new tag? (Unless it has already been used many times)

Comment: @BhargavRao Will the tag disappear when there is zero question tagged with it?

Comment: Check this out [I made a typo in a new tag name, how can I correct that?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285006)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it does not even allow me to create [ruby-2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-2.3) because there already is [ruby2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby2.3). So, following @Bhargav Rao's suggestion in the comment, I will delete [ruby2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby2.3) for now, wait until 3 UTC, then tag the question with [ruby-2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-2.3).