# How can I correct a typo in a tag?

Tags: support, tags

This comes up every now and then; I have checked various answers, but I couldn't find an adequate answer.
E.g.: [I made a typo in a new tag name, how can I correct that?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285006/i-made-a-typo-in-a-new-tag-name-how-can-i-correct-that)

I made a typo in a new tag [deep-fake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deep-fake).
As it turns out, it's a single word [deepfake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deepfake)

Correcting this error by removing the tag and recreate it as [deepfake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deepfake), gives me an error that the tag is too similar to [deep-fake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deep-fake), and hence cannot be created.

Should I remove the tag from the question and wait - and hope - the [deep-fake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deep-fake) will not be used and removed?

Comment: There is a single question tagged "deep-fake" - I'd probably just remove the tag, wait for it to be cleaned up, then re-create the tag. Set a reminder or something. Although, looking at the question - are you sure the tag is even appropriate? I thought "deepfake" was a specific product (or tech stack? not very well versed here) - the question seems to ask for something *similar* but not that specific solution.

Comment: "*Should I remove the tag from the question and wait - and hope - the deep-fake will not be used*" - the tag hasn't been used so far, so chances are quite good it's not going to be used in the next 24-ish hours. Enough time for the cleanup to run.

Comment: @VLAZ: thank you for your advise. I'll take this as guideline if something similar happens. Btw; deepfake is mainly a "way" of using AI to replace something in video (or photo) streams with something else.

Comment: Ah, OK, in that case. I just wasn't sure if it referred to a specific thing or the more generic approach. I was just aware of the end result and was under the impression it's a specific thing.